# Javascript: How can I mix in methods of another Object B to my Object A without copying but with linking?

Tags: javascript, pointers, mixins, assignment-operator

If I create an Object A:

```
let A = {};
```

And want to mix in methods from another Object B:

```
let B = {
    foo() {
        alert("Boo!");
    }
};
```

Normally I would call:

```
Object.assign(A, B);
```

Then I change my function foo:

```
Object.assign(B, {
    foo() {
        alert("Hooray!");
    }
});
```

After that I call foo:

```
A.foo(); // Actual output: "Boo!"
```

But I want that output to be "Hooray!".
So far I found out, that Object.assign only copies methods in the target, but it doesn't link them. 
About inheritance and composition I found useful blogposts here:[Why prototypical inheritance matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/) and most dominantly here: [Understanding Prototypes, Delegation & Composition](http://www.datchley.name/understanding-prototypes-delegation-composition/)

I want to mix a method in an Object, but not copy the methods, much more rather I want an assignment to the definition of the mixed in function.

How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried calling Object.assign(A, B); again after you change the function?

Comment: So basically when you assign `A` some function from `B`, and then you *change that function from `B`* you want that change to appear in `A`'s version as well?

Comment: @RenCamp You are right, this is a possible solution to update my code. But the question is whether there is a possibility without explicitly copying the function?
@ NickZuber Yes, exactly.

Comment: I uploaded a new (very similar) question regarding multiple independent Objects! Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080643/javascript-how-can-i-mix-in-methods-of-other-objects-b-c-to-my-object-a-withou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype inheritance comes to your rescue:

```
var A = Object.create(B);
A.foo();
B.foo = …;
A.foo(); // something else
```

Of course, this is not strictly a "mixin" any more, and you can only inherit via the prototype link from one other object only (though you can build an inheritance chain).

If you are looking to mix multiple independent objects into your existing `A` object, then that is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: …there *is* a way in ES6 using proxies, but you probably don't want that.

Comment: I don't care how it works, if it is possible, ES6 and proxies are fine! Please answer to my new question. Thank you very much, your help is appreciated!! :)

Comment: @FloJ12: Georg basically already gave [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36081018/1048572) I'd have given

Answer (score 0):

either, you call assign again. or you can do something like this: (there are no pointers in javascript, however: objects are always passed by reference (in contrast to normal values like numbers, strings,.. which are passed by value).

Hence:

```
var my = {
   f: function() { return "haa" }
}

var o1 = {};
Object.assign(o1, {my: my}); // this is the crucial point, you are assigning a reference to my
o1.my.f() // "haa";
my.f = function() { return "hoooo" };
o1.my.f() // "hoooo";
```

---

After some research, I found something much simpler:

```
var my = {
   f: function() { return "haa" }
}

var o1 = new Object(my); // create an object of the prototype my;

o1.f(); // haa;

my.f = function() { return "hoooo" };

o1.f() // hoooo
```

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle, it says A.foo() is not a function
I typed: 
Object.assign(A, {B: B});

I guess this is because Object.assign is not "deep"?
I mean it doesn't add methods of objects of objects...

Comment: sorry, I had a typo in the code. now it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/csfL6184/

Comment: Another remark: It worked with Object.assign(o1, {f: my}) and calling o1.f.f(), but again, this is not exactly what I want...

Comment: japp, this is what I updated in the fiddle. Well, I know what you want, but this is not possible in JavaScript. You want immediately add a function as a reference/pointer (like &sth in C), but in JavaScript only objects are passed like this. Functions, numbers, booleans, Strings can only be passed by value. So you need this extra step of wrapping your function into an object.

Comment: Hm in the first link I posted the blogger said (scroll down a little):
Propagating changes to prototypes, I think that this describes this somewhat? But I don't understand the code as I am no expert JavaScript dev...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, check out my answer - I added something that might fit better.

Comment: "*`new Object(my); // create an object of the prototype my;`*" does not do what you think it does

Comment: could you explain this? At leat for this example it does what I think: https://jsfiddle.net/dLp9mtkm/